# How to name multiple pdf files (with different names) in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, pdf, matrix

Dates (matrix)

```
V1         V2       V3
 1    14/11/2016   20161411
 2    15/11/2016   20161511
```

I want to create 2 pdf file with these names through a loop

```
1) 20161411.pdf
2) 20161511.pdf

for i in 1:2
pdf(file=as.character(Dates[i,3])
plot (my chart)
dev.off ()
```

the code isn't good but that's the main idea of the output I want. 
I don't want to write `pdf(file="20161411.pdf")`

Comment: `pdf(file = paste0(Dates[i, 3], '.pdf'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. This will give you the file name you want, I leave it to you to pass it to the pdf device.

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  print(paste(as.character(Dates[i,3]),'.pdf',sep=''))
        }
```